# how to write a query in php with set in it

Tags: php, mysql, initialization

i have a query witch has a set in it. how can i use this query in `php?`
the result is correct in `phpmyadmin` or workbench but there no response in `php` code.

```
set @num := 0, @ci := -1;
select currency_id,buy,sell 
from
  (select *,
    @num := if(@ci = currency_id, @num + 1, 1) as gp_number,
    @ci := currency_id as dummy 
  from currency_price
  order by `currency_id`, cu_date desc,buy,sell) x 
where gp_number=2
order by currency_id
```

when i want to put it in the `$conn->query` it doesn't do anything.

i try many ways but cannot

Comment: it is effectively multiple queries

Comment: If you are using `mysqli` you can utilise the `multiquery` method available, if it is PDO then you can set the attributre on the connection `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`

Answer (score 1):

@RamRaider is right. You have two queries here. The first is the line at the top of your example with the `set` operations, and the second is the query itself.

phpmyadmin, when it encounters a list of queries, politely runs them one after the other. But the various php MySQL APIs don't. You have to run each query with a separate use of `$conn->query()`.

Or you can refactor this to fit in just one query. In MySQL dialect this:

```
 SET @a :=1 ;
 SET @b := 1;
 SELECT @a := a+1 a,
        @b := b-1 b,
        col, col, col
   FROM table
```

can be refactored by joining to an initialization "table" like this:

```
 SELECT @a := a+1 a,
        @b := b-1 b,
        col, col, col
   FROM table
   JOIN (SELECT @a := 1, @b := 1) init
```

As long as that JOIN doesn't have an `ON` condition in it the query planner only runs the initialization select just once.

Comment: can u explane more?
or can u complitly write these 2 query to one query for me?

Comment: @SoheilAraei - The first is the basic structure of your query, and is more than 1 statement. The basic php Mysql query functions only process a single statement (which could be regarded as very basic and quite poor protection against SQL injection). The 2nd statement joins to a sub query (which will be executed first when the query is executed), and the variables are initialised in the subquery.